# What is the proper translation of Revelation 6:16-17?

Tags: revelation, textual-criticism

[Berean Study Bible](http://biblehub.com/bsb/revelation/6.htm)

> 16 And they said to the mountains and the rocks, “Fall on us and hide
>   us from the face of the One seated on the throne, and from the wrath
>   of the Lamb. 17 For the great day of **Their** wrath has come, and who is
>   able to withstand it?”

[King James Version](http://biblehub.com/kjv/revelation/6.htm)

> 16 And said to the mountains and rocks, Fall on us, and hide us from
>   the face of him that sitteth on the throne, and from the wrath of the
>   Lamb: 17 For the great day of **his** wrath is come; and who shall be able
>   to stand?

[Aramaic Bible in Plain English](http://biblehub.com/aramaic-plain-english/revelation/6.htm)

> 16 And they said to the mountains and rocks, "Fall on us and hide us
>   from before the face of the Lamb," 17 "Because the great day of **his** *
>   anger has come, and who is able to stand?"

So, is "his" appropriate, or is "their" more accurate? Do the manuscripts indicate either way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is, of course, a textual variant that is the basis for the different translations. According to Constantin Tischendorf in his *Novum Testamentum Graece*,<sup>1</sup>

[image: Tischendorf, Novum Testamentum Graece, Vol. 2, p. 944, Rev. 6:17]

In summary,

> “their wrath” (τησ [sic] οργησ [sic] αυτων) – [occurs] with Codex Sinaiticus (א),<sup>2</sup> Codex Ephraemi Rescriptus (C),<sup>3</sup> Miniscule 38,<sup>4</sup> the Vulgate (which has the Latin equivalent, *ipsorum*),<sup>5</sup> the Syriac Peshitta (which has the Syraic equivalent ܕܿܪܘܼܓܼܙܗܘܼܢ),<sup>6</sup> St. Prosper of Aquitaine in his *Liber de Prædictionibus et promissionibus Dei* (“The Book on the Predictions and the Promises of God”),<sup>7</sup> St. (Bishop) Fulgentius of Ruspe in his second epistle,<sup>8</sup> Haymo (Haimo) (Bishop) of Halberstadt in his *Expositio in Apocalypsin* (“Exposition on the Apocalypse”),<sup>9</sup> and others.
> The Textus Receptus,<sup>10</sup> Lachmann’s critical edition,<sup>11</sup> and Tischendorf’s critical edition<sup>12</sup> have the reading τ. οργ. αυτου (“his wrath”) along with Codex Alexandrinus (A),<sup>13</sup> Codex Vaticanus (B),<sup>14</sup> Codex Guelferbytanus (P),<sup>15</sup> nearly all others (*alli fere omnes*), including the Coptic,<sup>16</sup> Armenian,<sup>17</sup> Aethopian,<sup>18</sup> as well as Bishop Andreas of Caesarea (Ἀνδρέας Καισαρείας) in his Ἑρμηνεία εἰς τὴν Ἀποκάλυψιν (“Interpretation of the Apocalypse”),<sup>19</sup> Archbishop Arethas of Caesarea’s commentary on the Apocalypse which was based upon Bishop Andreas of Caesarea’s prior commentary,<sup>20</sup> and Bishop Primasius of Hadrumetum in his *Commentaria in Apocalypsim* (“Commentaries on the Apocalypse”).<sup>21</sup>

### Manuscript Weight

Arguably, manuscript evidence appears to favor the reading αὐτοῦ (“his”), referring to the Lamb.

### Context

Within the Book of Revelation (the Apocalypse), the noun ὀργή occurs six times.<sup>22</sup> In the verses excluding Rev. 6:16-17, the wrath belongs to the Almighty God, that is, God the Father. However, in Rev. 6:16, the wrath is specifically said to be the Lamb’s (viz., τῆς ὀργῆς τοῦ ἀρνίου). Therefore, in Rev. 6:17, it’s more likely that the wrath is the Lamb’s alone. On the other hand, the reading αὐτῶν is at least understandable since elsewhere the wrath is described as being God Almighty’s.

---

### References

Arethas Cæsareæ in Cappadocia Episcopus. “Commentario in Apocalypsin.” [Patrologiæ Cursus Completus: Series Græca Posterior.](https://books.google.com/books?id=gSFKAAAAcAAJ) Ed. Migne, Jacques Paul. Vol. 106. Petit-Montrouge: Imprimerie Catholique, 1863.

Primasii Episcopi Adrumetani. “Commentaria in Apocalypsim.” [*Patrologiæ Cursus Completus: Series Latina.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=g86LbPqzM5UC) Ed. Migne, Jacques Paul. Vol. 68. Petit-Montrouge: Imprimerie Catholique, 1866.

S. Andreas Cæsareæ Cappadociæ Archiepiscopus. “Ἑρμηνεία εἰς τὴν Ἀποκάλυψιν.” [*Patrologiæ Cursus Completus: Series Græca Posterior.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=gSFKAAAAcAAJ) Ed. Migne, Jacques Paul. Vol. 106. Petit-Montrouge: Imprimerie Catholique, 1863.

S. Fulgentius. “Epistola II.” [*Patrologiæ Cursus Completus: Series Prima.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=zBERAAAAYAAJ) Ed. Migne, Jacques Paul. Vol. 65. Petit-Montrouge: Imprimerie Catholique, 1847.

S. Prosperi Aquitani. “Liber de Prædictionibus et promissionibus Dei.” [*Patrologiæ Cursus Completus: Series Latina.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=8UCLym0mN28C) Ed. Migne, Jacques Paul. Vol. 51. Petit-Montrouge: Imprimerie Catholique, 1861.

Tischendorf, Constantin. [*Novum Testamentum Graece.*](https://archive.org/details/novumtestamentum02tisc) Vol. 2. Lipsiae: Giesecke, 1872.

Tischendorf, Constantin. [*Novum Testamentum Graece.*](https://archive.org/details/novumtestamentum31tisc) Vol. 3, Part 1. Lipsiae: Hinrichs, 1884.

Tischendorf, Constantin. [*Novum Testamentum Graece.*](https://archive.org/details/novumtestamentum32tisc) Vol. 3, Part 2. Lipsiae: Hinrichs, 1890.

Tischendorf, Constantin. [*Novum Testamentum Graece.*](https://archive.org/details/novumtestamentum33tisc) Vol. 3, Part 3. Lipsiae: Hinrichs, 1894.

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Vol. 2, p. [944](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum02tisc#page/944/mode/1up), Rev. 6:17
<sup>2</sup> *Novum Testamentum Graece*, Vol. 3, Part 1, p. [345-354](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum31tisc#page/344/mode/2up)
<sup>3</sup> *ibid*, p. [366-369](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum31tisc#page/366/mode/2up)
<sup>4</sup> *Novum Testamentum Graece*, Vol. 3, Part 2, p. [678](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum32tisc#page/678/mode/2up)
<sup>5</sup> *Novum Testamentum Graece*, Vol. 3, Part 3, p. [971-1108](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum33tisc#page/970/mode/2up)
<sup>6</sup> *ibid*, p. [807-859](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum33tisc#page/806/mode/2up)
<sup>7</sup> *Novum Testamentum Graece*, Vol. 3, Part 3, p. [1215](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum33tisc#page/1214/mode/2up); also see Migne, Vol. 51, *Liber de Prædictionibus et promissionibus Dei* (“The Book on the Predictions and the Promises of God”), Part IV, p. [850](https://books.google.com/books?id=8UCLym0mN28C&pg=RA1-PT11#v=onepage&q&f=true), Ch. 17
<sup>8</sup> *ibid*, p. [1190](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum33tisc#page/1190/mode/2up); also see Migne, Vol. 65, *Epistola II* (“Second Epistle”), p. [312](https://books.google.com/books?id=zBERAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA514#v=onepage&q&f=false), §6
<sup>9</sup> *ibid*, p. [1192](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum33tisc#page/1192/mode/2up); also see Migne, Vol. 118, *Expositio in Apocalypsin* (“Exposition on the Apocalypse”), p. [1033](https://archive.org/stream/patrologiaecurs31unkngoog#page/n520/mode/1up), Book II, Ch. VI
<sup>10</sup> *Novum Testamentum Graece*, Vol. 3, Part 1, p. [212-228](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum31tisc#page/216/mode/2up)
<sup>11</sup> *ibid*, p. [258-269](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum31tisc#page/258/mode/2up)
<sup>12</sup> *ibid*, p. [279-334](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum31tisc#page/278/mode/2up)
<sup>13</sup> *ibid*, p. [354-358](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum31tisc#page/354/mode/2up)
<sup>14</sup> *ibid*, p. [358-366](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum31tisc#page/358/mode/2up)
<sup>15</sup> *ibid*, p. [386-387](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum31tisc#page/386/mode/2up)
<sup>16</sup> *Novum Testamentum Graece*, Vol. 3, Part 3, p. [859-893](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum33tisc#page/858/mode/2up)
<sup>17</sup> *ibid*, p. [912-922](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum33tisc#page/912/mode/2up)
<sup>18</sup> *ibid*, p. [894-912](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum33tisc#page/858/mode/2up)
<sup>19</sup> *Novum Testamentum Graece*, Vol. 3, Part 3, p. [1159](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum33tisc#page/1159/mode/1up); also see Migne, Vol. 106, Ἑρμηνεία εἰς τὴν Ἀποκάλυψιν (“Interpretation on the Apocalypse”), p. [276](https://books.google.com/books?id=gSFKAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA275#v=onepage&q&f=true), Ch. XVIII, Rev. 6:14-17
<sup>20</sup> *ibid*, p. [1162](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum33tisc#page/1162/mode/1up); also see Migne, Vol. 106, *Exposition in Apocalypsin* (“Exposition on the Apocalypse”), p. [599](https://books.google.com/books?id=gSFKAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA538#v=onepage&q&f=false), Ch. XVIII, Rev. 6:14-17
<sup>21</sup> *ibid*, p. [1214](https://archive.org/stream/novumtestamentum33tisc#page/1214/mode/1up); also see Migne, Vol. 68, *Commentaria in Apocalypsim* (“Commentaries on the Apocalypse”), Book II, p. [840](https://books.google.com/books?id=g86LbPqzM5UC&pg=PT405#v=onepage&q&f=true)
<sup>22</sup> Rev. 6:16, 6:17, 11:18, 14:10, 16:19, 19:15